# convert numpy array of tuples to 2D array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tuples, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas DataFrame in which one of the columns is made of tuples of floats. When I use `arr = df['col_name'].to_numpy()`, I end up with a 1D array of tuples, but I need a 2D array of floats.

My solution so far is to use `arr = np.array(df['col_name'].to_list())`. This works, but it seems inefficient to convert first to a list and then to an array. So I'm wondering, is there a better way to do this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32422764/10863323) is related, but the only answer there points to reading a text file differently, which is not an option for me since the data is already in the DataFrame.

Comment: Is the dtype object?  The `tolist` step is probably fast.  An alternative might be `vstack`

Comment: Yes, both `df['col_name'].dtype` and `arr.dtype` return dtype('O'). So I should stick to the current approach?

Comment: An object array used reference/pointers just like python lists.  A pandas object dtype series also.  So `to_list` should be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

If your *col_name* contains **actual** tuples then run:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['col_name'].apply(pd.Series))
```

But if you have read your DataFrame e.g. from a CSV file, then each
element of *col_name* contains actually a **string** composed of:

- an opening parenthesis,
- a sequence of numbers (written as strings), separated with commas,
- a closing parenthesis,

and it only **looks** like a tuple.

If this is the case, run:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['col_name'].apply(lambda txt: pd.Series(eval(txt))))
```

In both cases the result is a DataFrame. If you need, convert it to
a *Numpy* array.

To check whether *col_name* contains **strings** or
actual **tuples**, using *Jupyter*, run:

```
df.col_name.iloc[0]
```

If the result is `'(2.15, 3.03, 4.07)'` (surrounded with quotes) it is
a **string**. But if you received `(2.15, 3.03, 4.07)` (without quotes) it is
a **tuple**.

Another way to check is to run `type(df.col_name.iloc[0])`.
You should get either *tuple* or *str*.

Comment: Thank you, it works (I have actual tuples). So to get the numpy array the final call would be `pd.DataFrame(df['col_name'].apply(pd.Series)).to_numpy()`. To me this looks less readable than my current approach, but I guess the gain is in efficiency, since it's skipping the conversion to list, right?

Comment: `pandas` apply operations are generally slow, since it's actually a row iterator.  This operation is making a new dataframe.  `timeit` to be sure.

Comment: I agree with @hpaulj, this is entirely unnecessary. Doubly so when OP is concerned about the performance of `.to_list()`.